# Save attachments, in two emails with identical subjects, based on file extension

Tags: vba, outlook

I get two emails with identical subjects, which contain different file formats.

The code indicates the file format and destination to send to.

However since the emails come in at the same time it's taking a csv file vs the xlsm and sending to another folder vs the folder in the code.

When I run the code manually it works.
When I let the code run naturally I get the reverse.

```vb
Public Sub NextEra(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\arthur\Dropbox\Apps\AutomatedPriceFileImports"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If (InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "NES Daily Matrix")) And Right(objAtt.FileName, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you setup an appropiate Outlook Rule to Run a script ``NextEra``? Note it only works when Outlook is running and has connection to the email server.

Comment: Hey Patrick, Thanks for participating. I have, the thing is this company sends us 2 separate emails contain the data in different formats. The outlook rule states to move them both since they're identical from the source but the vba negates the intended file format (xlsm) and chooses the csv which isn't mentioned at all as you can see.

Comment: Is it possible the attachment display name is different from the file name?

Comment: Try ``If (InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "NES Daily Matrix") > 0) And LCase(Mid(objAtt.FileName, InStrRev(objAtt.FileName, ".") + 1)) = "xlsm" Then``. Also saving the file with *DisplayName* will lose the file extension, is that intended?